# Removing the file paths and using the file number to perform some calculations while plotting

Tags: parsing, gnuplot

I am trying to read .txt files from a directory which have the following order;

```
x-23.txt
x-43.txt 
x-83.txt
:
:
x-243.txt
```

I am calling these files using `filename = system("ls ../Data/*.txt")`. The goal is to load these files and plot certain columns. At the same time, I am trying to parse the file names such that it would look like as below so that I can use them as title in the plot and add/subtract them from a certain column;

```
23
43
83
:
:
243
```

For that, I tried the following;

```
dirname = '../Data/'
str = system('echo "'.dirname. '" | perl -pe ''s/x[\d-](\d+).txt/\1.\2/'' ') 
cv = word(str, 1)
```

The above lines doesn't seem to trim and produce numbers on the files. The code all together;

```
filelist1 = system("ls ../Data/*.txt")
print filelist1
dirname = '../Data/'
str = system('echo "'.dirname. '" | perl -pe ''s/x[\d-](\d+).txt/\1.\2/'' ') 
cv = word(str, 1)
plot for [filename1 in filelist1] filename1 using (-cv/1000+ Tx($4)):(X($3)) with points pt 7 lc 6 title system('basename '.filename1),\
```

I am trying to use the file numbers "cv" after parsing the .txt files to subtract them from column `Tx($4)` while plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
directory = "../temp/"
filelist = system("cd ../temp/ ; ls *.txt")
files = words(filelist)
filename(i) = directory . word(filelist,i)
title(i) = word(filelist,i)[3 : strstrt(word(filelist,i),'.')-1]

plot for [i=1:files] filename(i) using ... title title(i)
```

Test case **(edited to show pulling files from another directory)**:

```
gnuplot> print filelist
x-234.txt
x-23.txt
x-2.txt
x-34.txt

gnuplot> do for [i=1:files] { print i, ": ", filename(i) }
1: ../temp/x-234.txt
2: ../temp/x-23.txt
3: ../temp/x-2.txt
4: ../temp/x-34.txt

gnuplot> plot for [i=1:files] x*i title title(i)
```

[image]

Comment: Everting looks great except when I recall the files from a directory e.g. ../Data/*.txt

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I want to use the above script to do the same in this following format "arrows_MEGA_oilFilter_1_finalCoor_-0.023_0_0.228_-0.023_0_0.388_Velocity_VortexMean_omegaMean_Unwv_bounacy_tauw_Forces_group5_fileA_group0Mean.txt
". The goal is to pull the value -0.023. Using your script, I tried title(i) = word(filelist,i)[32 : strstrt(word(filelist,i),'.')-1], however, it pulled only -0.. Any idea what should I add?

Comment: What is the exact format of that long character string?   Would you always want the 6 characters following the first underscore?

Comment: @Programming, which `-0.023` do you mean? the first one or the second one? My counting says 35 characters from the beginning for the first one. And `strstrt(word(filelist,i),'.')` gives the first occurence of `.`, so why `-1` instead of `+3`?

Comment: Thanks Theozh! I didn't think of the +3 :). It worked with me now.